# About isolated point of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for every homeomorphism  $f:X\to X$ with $d_{C^0}(f, id)<\delta$, we have $d(a, f^n(a))<\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

What can say about $a\in X$?

Is it true that $a$ is an isolated point for $X$?

Comment: By $f^n$ you mean $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f}_{n\text{ times}}$ or $(f(x))^n$. In the second case, is $X$ also a field or has some other algebraic structure?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος$f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism on metric space $X$

Comment: What is $d_{C^0}$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by $d_{C^0}$, but regardless of what that metric is you cannot conclude that a is an isolated point. Indeed, consider a subspace of the euclidean plane shaped like a cross (for example the union of the x- and y-axis) and let $a$ be the center of that cross. Then any homeomorphism from the cross onto itself must fix $a$. This is because for any other point on the cross there is a sufficiently small open ball around that point such that when removing a point from that ball the resulting set has two connected components, whereas when you take any open neighbourhood of $a$ and remove $a$ the resulting set has four or more connected components. Since $a$ is fixed by any homeomorphisms it trivially satisfies the property in your question, yet $a$ is not isolated.

Comment: two occurrences of "homomorphism" should be "homeomorphism"